# Lubuntu Mac Appearance

Tags: lubuntu, themes, appearance

I have lubuntu installed on my old Compaq Presario v5000 computer and it runs nicely for a lightweight OS, but I would like to have a Mac OS X style appearance.

I tried [this tutorial](http://namakutux.blogspot.be/2012/05/how-to-install-mac-os-x-lion-theme-on.html) but it didn't work right.

Do you have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: There were drop in themes for this with metacity and emerald, but I'm don't think they've have been updated recently.

Comment: Could you say what you tried? Which tutorial? what was wrong?

Comment: Oh btw I'm new at this so the more basic explanation the better thanks.

Comment: Ya I tried http://namakutux.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-install-mac-os-x-lion-theme-on.html this. And the icon theme I couldn't figure out, also the deck was cutting off he bottom of my windows

Comment: Hey hbdgaf, could you post a link to those metacity and emerald things.

Comment: The only metacity and emerald OS X things are for ubuntu. Can I do ubuntu packages on Lubuntu?

Comment: If someone could make something like this http://www.noobslab.com/2012/09/install-mac-x-reloaded-theme-on-ubuntu.html for Lubuntu that would be spectacular! @tim can I send you a picture of what is happening to my screen when I open a window?

Comment: Sure, upload it to http://imgur.com

Comment: Actually @Tim it just started working :)

Comment: But the windows look nothing like Mac still. I will upload a pjoto

Comment: Well look at the genius of Ask Ubuntu, infecting you without us doing anything ;)

Comment: Ha, yeah, something like that. Hey can you tell me the steps to change the icons and windows to look like Mac. I got lost in the instructions.

Comment: I don't understand what I did wrong with the icons, I installed mac-lion-icons-0.1-all.deb but I can't apply it. Same with mac osx-lode-0.1-all.deb thanks for the help @tim

Answer (score 1):

I recently configured my desktop to look like osx Yosemite, so have a look below and see if this configuration is any good for you:

Wallpaper - Upcoming default wallpaper for OS X Yosemite
Openbox theme (window theme; lxde is based on openbox) - Numix-Dark theme for Openbox
GTK theme - +Moka light
Dock - Cairo Dock
Dock theme - slightly modified version of Elementary theme
Icons - Numix-Circle
Cursor - DMZ Black
Fonts - Nimbus Sans L
Compositor - xcompmgr

Original post is: https://plus.google.com/114508537140833102142/posts/9uDNg3xtUuN

Comment: Nice! I like the MAC WINDOWS and logos better but that's my opinion. I have the Cairo Dock, but I need to figure out windows and icons

Comment: http://namakutux.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-install-mac-os-x-lion-theme-on.html

Comment: This works, it's a little confusing but after you install it all go under customize look and feel and click on all the OSX stuff.

Comment: Here is a picture link. http://imgur.com/Dh11466

Comment: Sorry for the crude photo.